# How to load assemblies using new AssemblyLoadContext in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, assemblyloadcontext

I am looking for community guidance to help me translate the below mentioned code to a new .NET 7 compatible version. Especially the bits and pieces inside `LoadModuleCatalog` method.

As per my research so far, the old AppDomain is no more applicable in .NET 7.0 version, instead a new [AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext) has been introduced by Microsoft to load assemblies but due to a lack of online documentation and resources on this topic, I am struggling to convert this code snippet to .NET 7 compliant version.

```cs
public class DynamicDirectoryModuleCatalog : ModuleCatalog
{
    void LoadModuleCatalog(string path, bool isFile = false)
    {
        AppDomain? parentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        Evidence evidence = new Evidence(parentDomain.Evidence);
        AppDomainSetup setup = parentDomain.SetupInformation;
        AppDomain childDomain =  AppDomain.CreateDomain("DiscoveryRegion", evidence, setup);

        try
        {
            List<string> loadedAssemblies = new List<string>();

            var assemblies = (
                 from Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                 where !(assembly is System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder)
                    && assembly.GetType().FullName != "System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder"
                    && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(assembly.Location)
                 select assembly.Location
                 );


            loadedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies);

            Type loaderType = typeof(InnerModuleInfoLoader);
            if (loaderType.Assembly != null)
            {
                var loader = (InnerModuleInfoLoader)childDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(loaderType.Assembly.Location, loaderType.FullName).Unwrap();
                loader.LoadAssemblies(loadedAssemblies);

                ModuleInfo[] modules = loader.GetModuleInfos(path, isFile);

                this.Items.AddRange(modules);

                if (isFile) LoadModules(modules);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(childDomain);
        }
    }

    private class InnerModuleInfoLoader : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic")]
        internal ModuleInfo[] GetModuleInfos(string path, bool isFile = false)
        {
            Assembly moduleReflectionOnlyAssembly =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies().First(
                    asm => asm.FullName == typeof(IModule).Assembly.FullName);

            Type IModuleType = moduleReflectionOnlyAssembly.GetType(typeof(IModule).FullName);

            FileSystemInfo info = null;
            if (isFile)
                info = new FileInfo(path);
            else
                info = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            ResolveEventHandler resolveEventHandler = delegate(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) { return OnReflectionOnlyResolve(args, info); };
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += resolveEventHandler;
            IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> modules = GetNotAllreadyLoadedModuleInfos(info, IModuleType);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve -= resolveEventHandler;

            return modules.ToArray();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<ModuleInfo> GetNotAllreadyLoadedModuleInfos(FileSystemInfo info, Type IModuleType)
        {
            List<FileInfo> validAssemblies = new List<FileInfo>();
            Assembly[] alreadyLoadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies();

            FileInfo fileInfo = info as FileInfo;
            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                if (alreadyLoadedAssemblies.FirstOrDefault(assembly => String.Compare(Path.GetFileName(assembly.Location), fileInfo.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) == null)
                {
                    var moduleInfos = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fileInfo.FullName).GetExportedTypes()
                    .Where(IModuleType.IsAssignableFrom)
                    .Where(t => t != IModuleType)
                    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract).Select(t => CreateModuleInfo(t));

                    return moduleInfos;
                }
            }

            DirectoryInfo directory = info as DirectoryInfo;

            var files = directory.GetFiles("*.dll").Where(file => alreadyLoadedAssemblies.
                FirstOrDefault(assembly => String.Compare(Path.GetFileName(assembly.Location), file.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) == null);

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file.FullName);
                    validAssemblies.Add(file);
                }
                catch (BadImageFormatException)
                {
                    // skip non-.NET Dlls
                }
            }

            return validAssemblies.SelectMany(file => Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file.FullName)
                                        .GetExportedTypes()
                                        .Where(IModuleType.IsAssignableFrom)
                                        .Where(t => t != IModuleType)
                                        .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
                                        .Select(type => CreateModuleInfo(type)));
        }


        private static Assembly OnReflectionOnlyResolve(ResolveEventArgs args, FileSystemInfo info)
        {
            Assembly loadedAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(
                asm => string.Equals(asm.FullName, args.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (loadedAssembly != null)
            {
                return loadedAssembly;
            }

            DirectoryInfo directory = info as DirectoryInfo;
            if (directory != null)
            {
                AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
                string dependentAssemblyFilename = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, assemblyName.Name + ".dll");
                if (File.Exists(dependentAssemblyFilename))
                {
                    return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(dependentAssemblyFilename);
                }
            }

            return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic")]
        internal void LoadAssemblies(IEnumerable<string> assemblies)
        {
            foreach (string assemblyPath in assemblies)
            {
                try
                {
                    Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    // Continue loading assemblies even if an assembly can not be loaded in the new AppDomain
                }
            }
        }

        private static ModuleInfo CreateModuleInfo(Type type)
        {
            // create ModuleInfo, implementation is not relevant
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

This code is from [Brian Lagunas's blog post](https://brianlagunas.com/prism-dynamically-discover-and-load-modules-at-runtime/).

Comment: .NET 7 is .NET *Core* 7. There's no AppDomain in .NET Core. That article is 10 years old, about .NET Framework and a completely different version of Prism.. Why do you want this in the first place? I'd dare say, why do you want *Prism*? What existed back then was a "little bit" overengineered

Comment: Plenty docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext

Comment: I was using this class to load dynamic modules. Now I am working toward migrating the solution to .NET Core 7.

Comment: There was no DI in .NET Framework back in 2013 so Prism had to introduce its own and invent a *lot* of things. The use of AppDomains was part of that. If you search for `dynamic loading` in the current GitHub repo you'll find the built-in [DirectoryModuleCatalog](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/4167e97a56ed3e6fe996341b49eed021911d2678/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Modularity/DirectoryModuleCatalog.netcore.cs#L71).

Comment: You are right, and I know about DirectoryModuleCatalog but this implementation is still important if you want to customize the logic of loading selective plugins only. I have removed that logic from this implementation to make it relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Prism has evolved a *lot* since 2013. That article was written for a completely different runtime and a completely different version of Prism. Back then there was no DI built into .NET Framework so Prism ended up being a "bit" overengineered.

Module loading from a directory is available out of the box using the built-in [DirectoryModuleCatalog](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/4167e97a56ed3e6fe996341b49eed021911d2678/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Modularity/DirectoryModuleCatalog.netcore.cs#L23) class. The class doesn't use `AssemblyLoadContext` at all. In fact, the code looks quite similar to the original article so one would have to do a `diff` to find what's different.

The [HelloWorld](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/4167e97a56ed3e6fe996341b49eed021911d2678/e2e/Wpf/HelloWorld/App.xaml.cs#L39) example app shows how to use various module catalogs by overriding `App.CreateModuleCatalog`, eg :

```
public partial class App
{
    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSharedSamples();
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = "Modules" }; 
    };
}
```

`ConfigureModuleCatalog` is replaced by `CreateModuleCatalog` that adds compiled modules from the `Modules` folder

Comment: The DirectoryModuleCatalog does a one time scan of the directory and then loads all the modules that it finds, however the provided solution by Brian Lagunas is to enable dynamic loading of new module assembly by dropped it into the folder. The same is also explained in the article and DirectoryModuleCatalog was available since then.